# Get AWS S3 Bucket Object Using PowerShell DSC

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

Using PowerShell DSC, I'm trying to read an object from within an AWS S3 bucket but I get the following error:

**Unable to load stored credentials for profile = [default]**

I have tried using the -ProfileLocation parameter however that then throw the error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ProfileLocation'". My code is as follows:

```
Read-S3Object -ProfileName default BucketName $bucket -Key $key -File $file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have read this documentation "[Using AWS Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html)" and followed the instructions it provided.

**Troubleshooting**

- `ProfileName` is not supported in the AWS Powershell Tools prior to version v1.1.  You can check your version through the `Get-AWSPowerShellVersion` cmdlet.  If you are using an earlier version, try using the `StoredCredentials` parameter instead.  Alternatively, you can update.
- Make sure that the profile name "default" actually exists.  You can check this by running `Get-AWSCredentials -ListStoredCredentials`, which will return a list of stored AWS credentials.
- If your desired profile name does not exist, you will need to create it.

The documentation provides the following example for creating a new profile:

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE `
                   -SecretKey wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY `
                   -StoreAs MyProfileName
```

Note: Concerning terminology, *Stored Credential* and *Profile* seem to be used interchangeably by the documentation.